# embed function in gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

Is there a way to embed the function `edit(dataframe)` in `gwindow`?
example:

```
DataFrame <- data.frame(cbind(1,1:10)
edit(DataFrame)
Window <- gwindow()
```

I would like to embed `edit(DataFrame)` in Window.

Apostolos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be through a button click.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10))
win <- gwindow()
btnEdit <- gbutton(
  "Edit", 
  container = win,
  handler = function(h, ...) dfr <<- edit(dfr)
)
```

---

You can be even fancier and decide whether or not the data frame should be editable or just viewable.

```
win <- gwindow()
btnEdit <- gbutton(
  "Edit", 
  container = win,
  handler = function(h, ...) 
  {
    if(svalue(chkReadonly)) View(dfr) else dfr <<- edit(dfr)
  }
)
chkReadonly <- gcheckbox(
  "Read-only", 
  FALSE,
  container = win,
  handler = function(h, ...) 
  {
    svalue(btnEdit) <- if(svalue(h$obj)) "View" else "Edit"
  }
)
```

---

Based upon your comment, what you want is even easier.  Store the data frame in a `gdf`.

```
tbl <- gdf(dfr, container = win)
```

Comment: The code above embeds the button into the widget but I want to embed the output of the function into it.TNX

Comment: Well, Richie answered as I would have (well, better really), but you may be looking for assigning into the tbl object he creates with [<- ?